# Create \congrightarrow with STIX

Tags: symbols, arrows, stix

I'm using STIX and I'd like to create this arrow:

```
\congrightarrow
```

editing the the `\equalrightarrow`, i. e., substituing the =-symbol with the `$\cong$`-one. Is it possible? Thank you so much

**My First Edit:** I thought this (for the solution):

```
\xrightarrow[]{\!\!\cong\textcolor{white}{W}}
```

But my main problem is this: How can I lower the symbol of $\cong$ above-left of the `\xrightarrow[]{}`? Moreover I use `\textcolor{white}{W}` only to create space. Does exist a better solution? If so, I pray you to show it. Thank you again in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Superimpose `\sim` to the symbol, with a slight push to the right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}

\newcommand{\congrightarrow}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \vbox{%
      \offinterlineskip
      \ialign{%
        $##$\cr
        \scriptscriptstyle\mkern4mu\sim\cr
        \equalrightarrow\cr
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\equalrightarrow$ $\congrightarrow$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This won't scale in subscripts or superscripts, but I don't think it's needed.

The “long” versions with `stix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}

\newcommand{\congrightarrow}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \vbox{%
      \offinterlineskip
      \ialign{%
        $##$\cr
        \scriptscriptstyle\mkern4mu\sim\cr
        \equalrightarrow\cr
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\equallongrightarrow}{\genericlongrightarrow{=}{0}}
\newcommand{\conglongrightarrow}{\genericlongrightarrow{\cong}{0.25}}
\newcommand{\genericlongrightarrow}[2]{%
  \overset{#1\;}{\mathrel{\rule{0pt}{#2ex}\smash[t]{\longrightarrow}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$A\equalrightarrow B \congrightarrow C$

$A\equallongrightarrow B \conglongrightarrow C$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you at all. But if I'd like to create a sort of `\longcongrightarrow`, how should I do? Thanks again (You can answer my comment or can edit your answers)

Comment: @Puck That's not what you asked for.

Comment: Unfortunately the graphic rendering is poor (because I use STIX and not STIX2 - And I'd not like to use STIX2). Hence I'll edit soon my question.

Comment: @Puck You *should* use `stix2`, which is supported. Anyway, I added the long versions with `stix`: as you see, the short version is essentially identical to the first part of the answer. I see no “poor rendering”.

Comment: @egreg: Interesting that the `\sim` symbol does not have quite the same shape as the `\cong` symbol in `stix`. They appear identical in CM.

Comment: @SandyG In CM the `\cong` symbol is obtained by superimposing `\sim` to `=`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\fsize}
\setlength{\fsize}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother
\newlength{\congkern}
\newlength{\congraise}
\newlength{\cliparrow}
\setlength{\congkern}{.05\fsize}
\setlength{\congraise}{.4\fsize}
\setlength{\cliparrow}{.65\fsize}
\newcommand*{\longerarrow}{%
    \clipbox{\cliparrow{} 0 0 0}{\(\longrightarrow\)}%
}
\newcommand*{\congrightarrow}{%
    \mathrel{\ooalign{%
        \kern\congkern\raisebox{\congraise}{\(\scriptstyle\cong\)}\cr%
        \(\longerarrow\)%
    }}%
}
\begin{document}
\(A \equalrightarrow B\)

\(A \congrightarrow B\)
\end{document}
```

I could not get the size of the `\cong` symbol to match exactly that of the `=` symbol of `\equalrightarrow`, because the latter is a little smaller than `\scriptstyle`. I don't know if there is a way to select the font size manually (and more precisely) for the `\cong` symbol so that they match exactly.